# SSMS 2017 can't connect to SSIS (SQL Server Developer 2017)

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to connect to Integrations services for the first time, I am using SSMS 2017, and my SQL Server is SQL Server Developer 2017.

Both are on 2017, but I get the following error, does anyone know how to get around this issue? Thanks in advance.

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-9V8LFD7.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "DESKTOP-9V8LFD7" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506689

---

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "DESKTOP-9V8LFD7" failed with the following error: "Class not registered".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools. Instead, add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: This is covered in the MSDN forums under https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/19fd5789-4b6b-4b45-987d-0a3995651b49/not-able-to-connect-integration-services-through-ssms-in-sql-server-2016?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: thank you - it talks about remotely logging into a Server Manager, I don't seem to have that on my machine, can you advise on how that can be obtained? I'm not a full on DBA so I'm not familar with provisioning servers etc

Comment: Obtained what @tomohiro?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Arthur, it appears that this was covered in an MSDN article. I followed [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3086/how-to-resolve-ssis-access-denied-error-in-sql-server-management-studio/) to a very well-informed article detailing the fix.